# April Fool Colored Comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, user-interface

I loved the colored  comments yesterday....

They looked more structured and were easier to read for me.

May this feature can be added and toggled on/off and configured in the user settings?

Comment: Or possibly, CSS changed by user scripts?

Comment: yepp, would be cool if the SE mods or whoever, could upload it with some explanations. Unfortunately i have not saved the page yesterday.

Comment: check this out `$('.comment-text').css({'color':'red'})` you can change to whatever font you want

Comment: Easier to read? Really? It burned my eyes :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's beyond me how you could possibly find that more structured and easier to read, and we certainly will not make it a feature. Here's the CSS though, in case you want to do it yourself:

```css
.comment-copy {
    font-family: 'Comic Sans MS', cursive !important;
    color: #00e0e0;
}
.comment-copy i {
    color: magenta;
}
.comment-copy b {
    color: red;
}
```

Adding that as a stylesheet was all the power-up did.

Comment: thanks for sharing, i have added it for Stackoverflow on Stylebot, so that whoever likes it aswell can use it: http://stylebot.me/styles/5300 may add the link to your answer.

Comment: Any plans of userscriptifying the unicorn vote thing?