# You can't see the question owner's special color

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

When the owner of a question comments on their question or an answer to their question or self-answers their question, they get a special color for the box around their username.

The problem is, you can't see the box:

> [image]

Can you please make this not white on white?

Comment: And if you love us in the slightest, please make it a red freehand circle instead of just a highlight.

Comment: How did you discover an invisible box? Are you a superhero?

Comment: @n.1, if you hover over the comment, the background of the comment turns a light blue. You can then see the author's name in a white box.

Comment: Man...things must be going *really* smoothly on the SE network for this to have a bounty.

Comment: Haha, I agree that it should be fixed.  I just disagree about the urgency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jin has just pushed a fix for this. In a few hours, the OP's name should be highlighted in blue, as was always intended.

Comment: "A few hours" -> now. Thanks!

Comment: with 40 minutes to spare on the bounty!

Comment: @mhlester actually 20 hours, there's a 24 hours grace period. :D

Comment: Good work! Why Jin became so shy of late? We don't bite!

Comment: yeah yeah, but the auto award doesn't happen in grace period. or does it? anyway, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/147574/jin?tab=bounties&sort=earned) makes me sad. Pops is a *thief!*

Comment: @mhlester indeed, auto award happens only when grace period end. The new favicon makes me sad.

Comment: yeah what's with that? there's no reason it shouldn't have just stayed the SE logo

Answer (score 21):

If I may suggest:

> [image]

Please note the following:

- The amazing quality of the freehand red circle
- The skill with which it is applied to the username
- The exact dimensions, in concordance with Atwood's Law of Freehand Red Circles
- The amazing dark-colored background behind the freehand red circle, which is an artifact of my stupidness when it comes to image editing.

[Kudos to Servy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229759/you-cant-see-the-question-owners-special-color#comment755348_229759) for the inspiration.

Comment: Ewwww. Much much too in the way.

Comment: But it's not red.. it's a sort of orange!

Comment: -1 for what @3ventic said.

Comment: **+1** Why downvote a good idea based on a minor colour inconsistency?

Comment: Is it bad that I actually really like this and would be happy if it got implemented? (Actually it kind of seems to fit best with the theme of Programmers, with the whiteboard thing and all, but still...)

Comment: Was I only the one who searched for *Atwood's Law of Freehand Red Circles*?

Answer (score 19):

Beta sites use a [darker shade](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15452/is-this-seat-being-chased-or-is-the-person-in-it-being-chased-from-it) that doesn't seem out-of-place with the theme but is still easy to spot:

> [image]

Perhaps something similar could be added here.

Answer (score 17):

The closest I can get to [Undo's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229759/you-cant-see-the-question-owners-special-color/230027#230027) with pure CSS (no images) is:

```css
a.comment-user.owner {
    border: 3px solid #faa;
    border-radius: 53% 47%;
    padding: 0.4em !important;  /* override existing padding style */
    margin: -0.4em;
    background: transparent;
}
span.comment-copy {
    position: relative;  /* keep username border from overlapping text */
}
```

which looks like this:

> [image: Screenshot of red circled usernames]

It's not quite a red *freehand* circle, but it's close...

Comment: So heartless... Where is your feeling? That is like a robotic kiss. I will forever have nightmares about these soulless ellipses!

Comment: Userscript? Pretty please?

Comment: @michaelb958: You could just use the CSS above directly as a user style, but since you asked nicely... https://gist.github.com/vyznev/944e0ac962790bcc97d0

Answer (score 4):

As of today, version 1.16 of [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) now includes the following minimal CSS fix for this issue:

```css
a.owner, td.owner { background: #eef }
```

This causes the question poster's user card and username in comments to be shown on a light blue background, like this:

> [image: Screenshot]

Per the SOUP inclusion guidelines, I deliberately kept this fix as neutral and minimal as possible.  If you want something fancier, you can always [install](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/944e0ac962790bcc97d0/raw/74571aa81bfb649512fa001f81ba0e864b6f0409/metacircles.user.js) the [user script](https://gist.github.com/vyznev/944e0ac962790bcc97d0) I posted in [my other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231282) (which, yes, should be compatible with SOUP).

Comment: Eh, they did it while you did yours!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Huh... if that was a coincidence, it's a pretty impressive one, considering that I've been sitting on this fix for almost a month. (Release schedule? What release schedule?)

Comment: Well, check the source... if it's your code demand a salary. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Well, kinda a coincidence... this answer reminded me so I just poked a helpful CM *cough* Pops *cough*. ;P

Answer (score 1):

*Insert standard story about getting tired of waiting for a fix and deciding to DO something.*

<s>Shamelessly ripping off</s> <s>Totally copy/pasting from</s> Incorporating Ilmari Karonen's comment markup, here's a slightly more reasonable style:

```css
td.owner{
    background-color:#E1ECF9 !important /*Same colour as on beta sites.*/
}
.owner
{
    background-color: #E1ECF9 !important
}

/*strip these next two if you plan to copy/paste and just want highlights without pretty shapes.*/

a.comment-user.owner {
    border-radius: 53% 47%;
    padding: 0.4em !important;  /* override existing padding style */
    margin: -0.4em;
    background: transparent;
}
span.comment-copy {
    position: relative;  /* keep username border from overlapping text */
}
```

I also modified the OP signature to show up more nicely on the question. It ends up looking like this:

[image: OP usercard and comments are now visible]

Comment: For the record, I don't actually know CSS. The copypasta bit is mostly true. [My first attempt](http://i.stack.imgur.com/btjWu.png) was an interesting mutation. "NOW WITH NON-FREEHAND NON-CIRCLES."

Comment: Must... resist... urge to burninate... Comic Sans....

Comment: [It's all Balpha's fault](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228037/228098).

Comment: For just a second I thought those were the actual comments to this post...