# Make OP background more prominent

Tags: bug, design, meta

In most SE sites, asker has a highlighted background in answers and comments for easy identification. MSE doesn't have such thing. The problem is in the `.owner` `background-color` CSS rule that is set for `#FFF` (aka white) which is exactly the same as well, the white background.

In this screenshot I "fixed" the `td` background color, but not in comments since `td.owner` had priority:

[image]

Comment: Though I see where you're coming _please_ don't use that colour - it doesn't go with my background :-(.

Comment: Yeah, it's really hard to read the blue user name on that blue background.  But something lighter would be fine.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards wasn't me that decided the color ;)

Comment: Related: [You can't see the question owner's special comment color](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229759/you-cant-see-the-question-owners-special-comment-color)